# Find and execute files whit ()

Tags: json, bash, shell, unix

I had this files.

```
1.json3
1(1).json3
1(2).json3
```

When i run this command

```
find . -type f -name '*.json3' -exec sh -c 'curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @{} https://api.myweb.com/api > {}.ml' \;
```

the result is this

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I think is abount (1).
How to perform a find like this ?
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to quote the arguments which will contain parentheses after substitution -- as you did for the `Content-Type:` argument -- so that the shell doesn't try to parse the special characters (note: there are two places where I inserted quotes):

```
find . -type f -name '*.json3' -exec sh -c 'curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "@{}" https://api.myweb.com/api > "{}.ml"' \;
```